# Codeigniter controller and model design for analytics dashboard

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on the analytic dashboard using codeigniter . Now I got confused about the controllers and models.

This application has different pages .Each pages are representing different  reports.
 So what is the best way to design the controller and models. Is it good to keep different controller,model and view for each report?  or a single controller for application

Please suggest me.

Comment: Depends upon your choices, nothing is hard bound, but for clarity I would suggest a different controller and a related model / view for each of your reports.

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion better to use HMVC, even me also used this structure for one of my application. HMVC using module structure. For dashboard purpose we can call particular function from each controller

eg:

```
echo modules::run('module_name/controller_name/function_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may put all the reports related to dashboard in a single controller, but each with a different function name.

And in each function, you can load different views for them. As to model, it's better to match your database table, each model to a table.

For example, you may name the controller `dashboard`, and there are several functions in it, namely `report1`, `report2`, `report3`. The corresponding url is `http://hostname/index.php/dashboard/report1` `http://hostname/index.php/dashboard/report2`  `http://hostname/index.php/dashboard/report3`